# vue code can't send value to my parameter.what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

As my code, parameter `dbtask` is alway `null`.

And from http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/, we can get data as below:

```
[{"idknowledgedescription": null, "idexercise": null, "answerpath": "浙江数学文testpdf.pdf", "value": null, "iddailytask": 1, "briefanswer": "A", "time": null, "idstudents": 1, "exercisepath": "浙江数学文testpdf.pdf", "timeofplan": "2018-03-15", "timeoflearn": "2018-03-15T00:00:00", "anserofstudent": null, "tipspath": "浙江数学文testpdf.pdf"}]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <script src="{% static 'jslib/vue.js'%}"></script>
      <script src="{% static 'jslib/reqwest.js'%}"></script>
      <script typet="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/semantic.min.css'%}" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
  </head>
      <body>
     {% verbatim %}
        <div id="app-6">

               <li v-for="t in  dbtask">
                {{t.exercisepath}}
            </li>

         </div>
      {% endverbatim %}

      </div>


      </body>
</html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var app6 = new Vue({
      el: '#app-6',
      data: {
         dbtask:null,
      },
      created() {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.bbb()
          }, 1000);
      },
      methods: {
        bbb: function() {
            var self=this;
            <!--var a={};-->
             $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/',function(task){
                          self.dbtask = task;
                          alert(self.dbtask[0].exercisepath);
                        });

        }.bind(this)
      }
    })
  </script>

`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your method declaration, remove `.bind(this)`. It will bind the method function to the `window` object, and not the Vue instance.

In other words, when you use `methods: { myMethod: function() { console.log(this); }.bind(this) }`, inside `myMethod` the `this` will be `window` and not the Vue instance.

Below a quick demo of this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    regularMethod: function () { console.log('regular method', this.message); },
    bindThisMethod: function () { console.log('method with .bind(this)', this.message); }.bind(this)
  },
  created() {
    this.regularMethod();
    this.bindThisMethod();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

Finally, here's how you should modify your code:

```
  methods: {
    bbb: function() {
        var self=this;
        <!--var a={};-->
         $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/',function(task){
                      self.dbtask = task;
                      alert(self.dbtask[0].exercisepath);
                    });

    // }.bind(this) // remove this
    }               // should be like this
  }
```

Comment: yes. it works. thank u for second time  you help me!

Comment: Of course, always glad to be of help! :)